# How to connect to MySQL from the command line

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, command-line, connection

How can you connect to MySQL from the command line in a Mac? (i.e. show me the code)

I'm doing a PHP/SQL tutorial, but it starts by assuming you're already in MySQL.

Answer (score 635, accepted):

See here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

```
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME
```

The options above means:

```
-u: username
-p: password (**no space between -p and the password text**)
-h: host
last one is name of the database that you wanted to connect.
```

Look into the link, it's detailed there!

---

As already mentioned by [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23642685/298455), you can avoid passing the password as the part of the command by not passing the password like this:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME -p
```

---

People editing this answer: PLEASE DONOT ADD A SPACE between `-p` and `PASSWORD`

Comment: thank you, 2 questions 1) do you have to include the  "- u"  "- p" etc, or are those replaced by the username etc 2) if there's no database created do you just leave that blank?

Comment: It is possible to set up MySQL authentication based on the user you logged in as, or not authenticate at all, but neither is a good idea,  Specifying the password on the command line is even a slight security risk because it ends up in your command history and process tables.  If you leave out the password it will ask you for it.

Comment: @Michael 1) updated. the ALL-CAPS needs to be replaced with actual values. leave the -u, -p, -h as it is 2) yes. After logging-in type `show databases` to see the list of databases.

Comment: @dj_segfault right. So, if you leave, `-p` without specifying the password, it will prompt you for password.

Comment: If you don't currently have a database created, you need to use the *mysqladmin* command to create one.  But I believe when you install the server, the default "mysql" database is created, that holds all the schema and authentication information.  You can log into that one (if you have sufficient privileges) and create other databases from there.

Comment: -P to use a port other than the default

Comment: Is there any way to pass in key value pair parameters along the schema name ? Say ones like `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Comment: I do not get a password prompt when I leave out the password parameter

Comment: Tip: Omit the database name argument if don't have a target database in mind. Then either run `SHOW DATABASES ;` to see a list, or run `CREATE DATABASE bogus_ ;`.

Answer (score 190):

Best practice would be to `mysql -u root -p`.
Then MySQL will prompt for password after you hit enter.

Comment: To elaborate, this keeps your password from showing up in `.bash_history`.  Using the current top-voted method, if someone gains access to `$HOME` (and thus `.bash_history`), they also have your authentication details -- scary!  This kind of intrusion can (and [does](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/08/0-day-attack-on-firefox-users-stole-password-and-key-data-patch-now/)) happen...

Comment: You could execute a bash command without without it showing up in the .bash_profie. Read more here: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1512/execute-a-command-without-saving-it-in-the-history#comment

Comment: @Jeremy Not only in `.bash_history` but in `top` and more tools too! You can even have your files secure, just share the computer with another legitimate user.

Comment: +1 because my password has special symbols in it and it won't parse when part of the command, it has to be done separately.

Answer (score 25):

After you run MySQL Shell and you have seen  following:

```
mysql-js>
```

Firstly, you should:

```
mysql-js>\sql
```

Secondly:

```
 mysql-sql>\connect username@servername (root@localhost)
```

And finally:

```
Enter password:*********
```

Comment: How can import a mysql file if I only have the shell? It will not see my local file system. Do I need a client or IS the Shell a client?

Answer (score 17):

Short, sweet, and complete: (and also secure)

`mysql -u <username> -h <hostname> -P <port> <database> -p`

This will

1. Connect you to a remote database (including port)
2. Not store your password in your `.bash_history`

Answer (score 13):

Use the following command to get connected to your MySQL database

mysql -u USERNAME -h HOSTNAME -p

Answer (score 8):

Use below command to do the login to remote mysql server

```
mysql -u property_wlive  -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 property_plive -p
```

Answer (score 7):

Everyone can log in to MySQL. *A password is needed and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line/77467429#77467429) explains how to log in to MySQL without a password prompt:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *****
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to connect to MySQL directly using proper MySQL username and password is:

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass
```

Here,

```
root is the MySQL username
mypass is the MySQL user password
```

This is useful if you have a blank password.

For example, if you have MySQL user called `root` with an empty password, just use

```
mysql --user=root --password=
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you may need to add `-P` for port:

```sql
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAME -P PORTNUMBER DATABASE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Oddly enough, despite there being a lot of (similar) answers, no one suggested this:

You can create a `.my.cnf` file in your $HOME folder, which contains:

```
[client]
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
database=google
user=root
password=root
```

And you'll only have to do

```
$> mysql
```

To connect to that database.

A few **key notes** to take into consideration :

- Storing the password in that file is not a good idea. At worst, please do a `chmod 400 .my.cnf`. But best is to store the password elsewhere. Other threads on StackOverflow offer great answers for that.
- You can customize the data in that file, and leave the rest to you. For instance, removing the `database` line allow you to do `mysql another-db-name`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! As you alluded to, If you don't want to hardcode the password you can omit it and then just run `mysql -p` to be prompted for the password interactively.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me ::-

```
mysql --host=hostNameorIp --user=username --password=password
```

or

```
mysql --host=hostNameorIp --user=username --password=password database_name
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it worked with the following command on Mac.

After you run MySQL Shell and you have seen the following:

```sh
mysql-js>
```

Firstly, you should:

```sh
mysql-js>\sql
```

Second step:

```sh
MySQL  SQL > \c --mysql username@host
```

Then finally provide the password as prompted

Answer (score 1):

Those steps worked for me with Windows 10

1. go to MySQL installation directory then access to bin directory (mysql.exe must be showed in list of files)
2. open cmd in the same location
3. run `mysql  -u [username] -p` (don't need to add -p if you didn't have set a password) then press enter

Answer (score 1):

if you use no password for entering the `mysql.server`

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 'port'
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can log in without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to `-p` or `--password=` as shown below. *Don't put any space just after `-p` or `--password=` because there is error:

```
mysql -u john -pbanana
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john --password=banana
```

Or, you can log in without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to `MYSQL_PWD=` as shown below. *[The doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) says `MYSQL_PWD is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.`:

```
MYSQL_PWD=banana mysql -u john
```

Or on Windows, you can set the user `john` and the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[client]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455487/using-my-ini-to-access-mysql-exe-from-the-commandline-without-p/77463735#77463735) explains how to log in by setting only the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini`:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="john"
password="banana"
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below:

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

*Not setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` gets error as shown below:

```
mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

The various commands shared here is matter of utilizing the flags(options) available to connect to certain state or quick authentication without password prompt. Let me sample a few ways to connect to my sql.

1. Connecting from the terminal

**Option 1:**

`mysql -u root -p` : This with connect to user called root, -p flag will prompt for a password.

**Option 2:**

`mysql -u root -p<PASSWORD>` : Here you enter the password directly into the command and after execution the server connects quick without password prompt.

The rest of the options will basically be centred on this two where you can use -h flag to include host among other configuration.

2. Connecting from the mysql shell
   First thing is to ensure you are in sql mode, use:

`\sql` to switch to sql mode from JS or Python mode.

To connect to mysql server, use:

`\connect username@hostname` **e.g**. `\connect root@localhost`