# Default MySQL database name

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to install mybb on a server but the admin is taking too long to respond. I have all the information I need except the database name. Is there a default name for mysql on a linux server?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no default database.

A fresh MySQL server install will have 0 databases. The install script will run `mysql_install_db` after the server is running to create a `mysql` database, which MySQL uses to store users and privileges. Don't put your data there.

You can create your own databases by issuing `CREATE DATABASE [name]` queries if your user has permission.

Comment: 0 databases, with the exception of information_schema, of course.

Comment: Let me put it this way - A fresh MySQL server and MySQL shell install will have the following 4 databases: 

(Version 5.5.42):
1. information_schema
2. mysql
3. performance_schema
4. test

Answer (score 3):

No there is not...............

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have full database access? Then just add a database with a name of your choice:

   ```
   CREATE DATABSE rob_bb;
   ```
2. If you only have a normal user access, the database name is often the same as the username.
3. Or you can run the query

   ```
   SHOW DATABASES;
   ```

to see what databases exist (which you are allowed to see).

Comment: where would i enter these commands? right now i have ftp access, and (i think) ssh

Comment: if you ssh in, you can use the command "mysql -p" to login to mysql.
if you only have ftp, you can add a script file, for example php:

    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
        $resource = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
        {
            echo implode("\t", $result) . "\n";
        }
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

There are no default databases. If you were asking about default users 'root' would be it.

Answer (score 0):

## No default database in MySQL

MySQL does *not* create a database by default for you. If connecting to a fresh MySQL server, you will find four databases existing, described below.

## 4 databases in MySQL

When first [connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5131931/642706) to a new MySQL 8.1 server on a terminal, like this:

```bash
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

… at the prompt you can issue this SQL command to see all existing databases:

```bash
SHOW DATABASES ;
```

You will find four databases:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

- The first is required by the SQL standard: `information_schema`. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema). See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/information-schema.html).
- `performance_schema` is a feature for monitoring MySQL Server execution at a low level. See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/performance-schema.html).
- `sys` is a set of objects that helps [DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator)s and developers interpret data collected by the Performance Schema. See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/sys-schema.html).

We can then create a database for our own purposes.

```bash
CREATE DATABASE bogus_ ;
```