# What is the MySQL JDBC connection string value for dbname when no databases exist?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-string

Apparently MySQL [has no default database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002126/4009451). I am attempting to connect a MySQL client to a brand-spanking-new MySQL server that has 0 databases. The thinking is that I would run some SQL scripts and create my databases/tables/etc. that way.

The JDBC connection string for MySQL apparently is of the form:

```
jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<dbname>[?<param1>=<value1>][&<param2>=<value2>]
```

Is `dbname` optional? If not, what can I specify (since there is currently no database to connect to)?

Comment: you're not connecting to a "database". you're connecting to the db via the host:3306. the dbname just specifies a default db that queries will target. should able to connect even w/o a default specified

Comment: and all the default does is let the db know which db a `select foo from sometable` should go into. an absolute `select foo from schema.table` would always work regardless.

Comment: @MarcB.  that should be an answer: "yes, dbname is optional. The "dbname" can be omitted from the JDBC connection string for MySQL Connector/J. As far as what can be specified, I think it has to be a database that exists.  The `mysql` database will exist, if it doesn't there's a big problem.  The `information_schema` database should also exist (in versions after 5.1).

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to specify a database name to connect to MySQL (although in general it is advisable to do so)