# MySQL root password change

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, root, mysqladmin

I have been trying to reset my MySQL root password. I have run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`, updated the root password, and checked the user table to make sure it is there.

Once restarting the MySQL daemon I tried logging in with the new root password that I just set and still get *Access denied* for user 'root' errors. I have also tried completely removing and reinstalling MySQL (including removing the `my.cnf` file) and still no luck. What can I do next?

Comment: please post your actual error

Comment: If your not locked out `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepassword');`  is safest.

Comment: I followed the steps in the video to change password in one of my servers https://youtu.be/gFo5DV_pSg8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: Server version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD("1")' at line 1

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("somepassword");

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has the root user's auth plugin as: auth_socket. That plugin does not support a password. There is an answer below that talks about it. Solution is to change the plugin and password in one statement : ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Password'; The "WITH  mysql_native_password" part changes the plugin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found it! I forgot to hash the password when I changed it.  I used this query to solve my problem:

`update user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';`

I forgot the `PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD')` and just put in the new password in plain text.

Comment: make sure you come back and accept your answer to allow others to see the solution

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html shows how to do this with `--init-file=` if your looked out.

Comment: Any idea why when I use the same command, the following error is returned?  Error 1054 (42S22): unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root'' at line 1

Comment: I too get this error. syntax error. Please add the solution.

Comment: where to run this query
i cannot get anything even for mysql -v

Answer (score 246):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This is working for me in 5.7 while the accepted answer is not.

Comment: This is the correct solution if your MySQL root password is set to blank.

Comment: > UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE user='root';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
In MySQL version 5.7.x there is no more password field in the mysql table. It was replaced with authentication_string.

Comment: @fschuindt Nope, I had MySQL 5.7 root with password, once I login in cli this code change the password to the new one.

Comment: @fschuindt Nope, I had MySQL 5.7 root with password, once I login in cli this code change the password to the new one.

Comment: where am I supposed to enter this?

Comment: This gives a OK to me, but don't actually do anything

Comment: It needs an extra command `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to make effective the change without restarting the database server.

Comment: I did this to the root account (which already had a password) and now neither password works and I'm locked out. Could be because the flush privileges command was missing... not sure right now.

Comment: @jeffmjack - I don't think it's because of the above command. It can be because of text encode issues. Anyway from memory mysql server daemon has the option to run sql to reset password during startup. It gives you an option to reset master password.

Comment: Note this command is specifically for @'localhost'. I went on a wild goose chase trying to figure out why a different machine could not connect with the new password. See `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;` to see various hosts to set the password for. (in my case @'%' for everywhere else)

Comment: i just remove PASSWORD function.

Answer (score 85):

Have a look at this from the MySQL reference manual:

First log in to MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then at the *mysql* prompt, run:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
```

Then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Look at this page for more information: *[Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)*

**UPDATE:**

For some versions of mysql, the password column is no longer available and you'll get this error:

`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'`

In this case, use `ALTER USER` as shown in [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53968240/1485347).

Comment: I got an error "You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column..." when updating the user's password. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench for how to work around this error.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'' at line 1

Comment: PASSWORD function seems to have been removed. See this thread for alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320576/in-mysql-server-8-0-the-password-function-not-working

Answer (score 39):

Please follow the below steps.

1. `sudo service mysql stop`
2. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. `sudo service mysql start`
4. `sudo mysql -u root`
5. `use mysql;`
6. `show tables;`
7. `describe user;`
8. `update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';`
9. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Log in with password *"1111"*.

Comment: `flush privileges` is important as a last step.

Comment: It's really done with the ass .I did all the tutorials to reset the password. Everything works except when I log in with the new password, it doesn't work.

Comment: if mysqld is not starting and message like this 
mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

do this:
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
chomod 777 /var/run/mysqld 
and start all from the begging

Comment: Step 2 - I advice to use: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking  &`  It is important to run the command ending with `&` so that it runs in the background. Passing `–skip-networking` option to skip networking that prevents other clients from connecting to the MySQL server. [Source](https://www.journaldev.com/39274/change-reset-mysql-mariadb-root-password)

Comment: [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) = *"sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can execute."*. How secure is that?

Comment: Brevity is good, but can you elaborate in your answer? E.g., ***why*** are the first three steps required? What will happen if they are not followed? Aren't steps 6 and 7 for informational purposes only (which ones?) and not really required? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42484420/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 33):

This is the updated answer for WAMP v3.0.6 and up.

In the MySQL command-line client, [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) or any MySQL GUI:

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
WHERE user='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In MySQL version 5.7.x there is no more password field in the MySQL table. It was replaced with *authentication_string*. (This is for the terminal/CLI.)

In the MySQL command-line client, [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) or any MySQL GUI:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE user='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This answer is one of the few who says that `mysql.user` table should be updated. Notice that if You are using any other database (set by the `use` command), You will get an error that the table `user` does not exist.
Thank You, sir!

Comment: works for me .  I am using 5.7.x , there's no `mysql.user` table. other answers are out-dated

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: I roll it back because it is my intention to use > because of the semicolon per line which is intended for the terminal

Comment: 0 rows affected, rows matched: 3 changed: 0 ... ?

Comment: looks like that is a newer version. What version of MYSQL are you working on with?

Comment: In MySQL 8.0+ the function PASSWORD can NOT EXISTS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320576/in-mysql-server-8-0-the-password-function-not-working . So, instead `PASSWORD('mypass')` you can use `CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('mypass')))))` that works as the old PASSWORD function worked.

Comment: @FlameStorm This saves the day. I think you should write an answer.

Answer (score 31):

I searched around as well and probably some answers do fit some situations,

my situation is Mysql 5.7 on a Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS system:

(get root privileges)

```
$ sudo bash
```

(set up password for root db user + implement security in steps)

```
# mysql_secure_installation
```

(give access to the root user via password instead of socket)

(+ edit: apparently, you need to set the password again?)

**(don't set it to 'mySecretPassword'!!!)**

```
# mysql -u root

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> set password for 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mySecretPassword'); 
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

# service mysql restart
```

Many thanks to [zetacu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580302/zetacu) (and [erich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4468423/erich)) for [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/2135941) (after searching a couple of hours...)

Enjoy :-D

S.

**Edit (2020):**

This method doesn't work anymore, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099028/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-want-to-configure-a-pa) for future reference...

Comment: This is the best answer so far, at least for mysql server 5.7.

Comment: The BEST answer. Thank you.

Comment: `mysql_secure_installation` worked for me after a fresh installation.

Answer (score 27):

On MySQL 8 you need to specify the password hashing method:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new-password';
```

Comment: The only worked for me.

Comment: Don't forget the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` too. This works if MySQL uses the new password hashing (I think it was introduced in MySQL 8.0, and was not mandatory at installation time, just recommended).

Answer (score 21):

**On MySQL 8.0.4+**

To update the current root user:

```
select current_user();
set password = 'new_password';
```

To update another user:

```
set password for 'otherUser'@'localhost' = 'new_password';
```

To set the password policy before updating the password:

```
set global validate_password.policy = 0;
set password = 'new_password';
set password for 'otherUser'@'localhost' = 'new_password';
```

Another / better way to update the root password:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Do you want to stick with 5.x authentication, so you can still use legacy applications?

In `my.cnf` file

```
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

To update *root*:

```
set global validate_password.policy = 0;
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'new_password';
```

Answer (score 13):

For MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

For MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Answer (score 12):

For me, only these steps could help me setting the root password on version 8.0.19:

```
mysql
SELECT user,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_pass_here';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT user,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
```

If you can see changes for the root user, then it works.
Source: *[Can't set root password MySQL Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-set-root-password-mysql-server)*

Comment: I don't know why setting the password for the MySQL `root` user has to be so obscure, but this worked on Ubuntu 21, MySQL 8. Thanks Sergey.

Comment: this is the ONLY answer that works along many answers on many questions for mysql 8

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on 5.7.40

Answer (score 6):

You have to reset the password! Steps for Mac OS X (tested and working) and Ubuntu:

Stop MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Start it in safe mode:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

(The above line is the whole command.)

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished, so open another shell/terminal window and log in without a password:

```
mysql -u root

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

Start MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Your new password is 'password'.

Comment: I've got a message : no database selected

Comment: @Mimouni try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y/25883967#25883967

Answer (score 6):

Using the **mysqladmin** command-line utility to alter the MySQL password:

```bash
mysqladmin --user=root --password=oldpassword password "newpassword"
```

[Source](http://www.ihp.sinica.edu.tw/dashboard/docs/reset-mysql-password.html)

Comment: This works, and works better as `mysqladmin -p password` prompting for old password once, and the new password twice.

Answer (score 6):

For the current latest MySQL version (8.0.16), none of these answers worked for me.

After looking at several different answers and combining them together, this is what I ended up using that worked:

```
update user set authentication_string='test' where user='root';
```

Comment: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` and then `[Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@localhost'; Ignoring user`

Answer (score 3):

I tried [the answer from kta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change/21808346#21808346), but it didn't work for me.

I am using MySQL 8.0.

This worked for me in the MySQL command-line client (executable `mysql`):

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'yourpassword'`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code  - how exactly does this solve a seven years old question?

Comment: It looks like the syntax has been changed over the seven years. It's not wrapping password with PASSWORD() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Answer (score 3):

---

***This is for Mac users.***

---

On 8.0.15 (maybe already before that version) the PASSWORD() function does not work. You have to do:

Make sure you have Stopped MySQL first (above).
Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Replace this mysqld_safe with your MySQL path like in my case it was

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables
```

then you have to perform the following steps.

```
mysql -u root

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Then

```
mysql -u root

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 21.04, MySQL 8

Answer (score 3):

Now just use:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR <user> = '<plaintext_password>'
```

Because `'SET PASSWORD FOR <user> = PASSWORD('<plaintext_password>')'` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.(Warning in 04/12 2021)
Please use `SET PASSWORD FOR <user> = '<plaintext_password>'` instead.

Update 04/12 2021 AM 2:22:07  UTC/GMT -5 hours.

Use the following statement to modify directly in the mysql command line:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpass');
```

or 1.The terminal enters the bin directory of MySQL

```bash
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
```

2.Open MySQL

```
mysql -u root -p
```

3.At this time you can use your default password

4.Perform operations in MySQL at this time

```
show databases;
```

5.You will be prompted to reset the root user password.

So how to reset the root password? I checked a lot of information but it didn’t take effect.

Including entering to modify the database in safe mode, using the mysqladmin command:
"`Mysqladmin -u root password"your-new-password"`"
etc.,
Will not work.

The correct steps are as follows:

1.It is still in the cd `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` directory

2.`sudo su`

After entering, you will be asked to enter your computer password.

When you enter it, nothing is displayed. After you enter it, press Enter

Then press enter

3.Cross the authorization verification

```
sh-3.2# ./mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

If the execution of the command is stopped, and the execution has been completed at this time,

press Enter directly, and then exit to exit:

```
sh-3.2# exit
```

4.Re-enter MySQL at this time, no -p parameter, no password

```
./mysql -u root
```

5.Select the database MySQL (here MySQL refers to a database in MySQL,

there are other databases in MySQL, you can view it through show databases;)

```
use mysql;
```

6.Update the password of the root user in the database table:

```
update user set authentication_string=‘123456’ where User='root';
```

Note: The password field here is `authentication_string`,

not the `password` circulated on the Internet.

It is estimated that MySQL was updated later.

Re-enter MySQL and use the password you just set, is it all right?

Because you have just set to bypass the authorization authentication,

you can log in to MySQL directly without a password.

My stupid way is to restart the computer and log in to MySQL with the password again to see if the modification is effective;

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 5.7, the password is replaced
with 'authentication_string'. Use

```
update user set authentication_string=password('myfavpassword') where user='root';
```

Answer (score 2):

So many comments, but I was helped by this method:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password 'my password'
```

In my case after installation I had got the MySQL service without a password for the root user, and I needed to set the password for my security.

Comment: It could be used to reset mysql root user password without knowing the old one. But make sure no one has access to your syslog, as this password is logged:
`Aug 07 16:21:55 ubuntupc sudo[93250]:   user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'my password'`

Answer (score 1):

A common error I run into from time to time, is that I forget the `-p` option, so be sure to use:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can change the password of the user `root` to `apple` with [ALTER USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html) or [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) as shown below. *You probably need to log in with the user `root`:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'apple';
```

*Don't use the command below to change the password of the user `root` to `apple` because the password does not work to log in to MySQL with the user `root`. Finally, you have to reset the password following [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html):

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='apple' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And, you can disable the password of the user `root` with `''` as shown below:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

Or:

```sql
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = '';
```

Then, you can log in with no password as shown below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) says `MYSQL_PWD is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line/77467429#77467429) explains how to log in to MySQL without a password prompt:

```
mysql -u root
```

Or:

```
mysql -u root --password=''
```

Or:

```
mysql -u root --password=''
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u root
```

And, you can log in with no password for the password prompt as shown below:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
mysql -u root --password
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Or:

```
MYSQL_PWD='' mysql -u root --password
Enter password:
```

Or on Windows, you can set the user `root` and no password under `[client]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[client]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448967/is-it-possible-to-store-a-password-in-my-ini-file/77466171#77466171) explains how to log in with `my.ini`:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="root"
password=""
```

Or:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="root"
# password=""
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below:

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

*Not setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` get error as shown below:

```
mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit from WAMP and Stop all WAMP services.

Open [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and then type:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
```

Then save it to the C: drive with any name... like this "c:/example.txt"

Now go to your "wamp" folder: *wamp* → *bin* → *mysql* → *mysql* (your version) → *bin*

In my case the path is "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin".

Now copy your path, run CMD with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and then type "cmd" (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Type `cd`, right click on CMD, and paste the path (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Now type (`mysqld --init-file=C:\\example.txt`) without braces and (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Then restart the PC or open [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) and kill *mysqld.exe*.

Start WAMP and your password will be removed...

Comment: On Windows, I presume (not stated).

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users, if you forget your root password, [thusharaK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change/28601069#28601069) is good, but there are a few more tricks:

If you are using a system preference to start MySQL serverside, simply

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

might not work for you.

You have to make sure the command-line arguments are the same with the system start configuration.

The following command works for me:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring --early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so --skip-grant-tables
```

You can use

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

to check your own.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use interactive configuration:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Resetting root password.

1. `sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`
2. `alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'new_password';`

Comment: THIS FILE IS OBSOLETE. STOP USING IT IF POSSIBLE. This file exists only for backwards compatibility for tools that run '--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf' and have root level access to the local filesystem. With those permissions one can run 'mariadb' directly anyway thanks to unix socket authentication and hence this file is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me.

That said, here is how I did it for the  password change to the root SQL profile if you can log in already.

While logged in:

Tool Bar -> Servers -> Users and Privileges -> select root - > from here you can change the password, or expire it and change it in the login.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Replace `5.5` with your current version and you will be asked for the new root password.

Comment: In what OS? This makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

1. On Mac open system preferences   *MySQL*.
2. In the configuration section of MySQL, check for *"Initialize Database"*.
3. Change the password in the prompt.

   [image: Initialize database]