# Cannot connect remotely to mysql server via heidisql

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to MySQL and php and i cannot seem to obtain a remote connection to mysql server via heidisql and i can get a connection via the command line shell included in the mysql client the following is the error message

```
SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user
'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

this message occurred once i typed in `-hlocalhost -uroot -pascent` in the DOS box. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.  Would i have to run the mysql_install_db script to initialise privilges as i am 100% sure my password is correct.

Comment: Usually you need three basic things to connect to a DB, you need the IP address and port. You need a DB created with tables, and you need a user with properly granted permissions to the DB.

Comment: thats exactly what i do have as in port 3306 and ip 127.0.0.1 and they do consist of tables as well

Comment: add `-p` param for Password.

Comment: IP, port, db, user; i think thats 4 ?

Comment: `Host`, `Port`, `Username`, `Password` and `Database`

Comment: yes ive added those bits in and the error message occurs if i change the port to 3307 then it doesn't come up.

Comment: The default root password is blank  `mysql -u root` <<< use that.. Then run `mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]` <<< set a password. Look at this other stack post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

Comment: In the local mysql server, you need to create a specific user to connect from your remote ip, grants permissions on that user, and open the port to accept connection from remote users

Comment: i have just tried this and nothing has changed. however the previous answer was interesting is there an link you could point me towards

Comment: I don't understand your question... do you have problems connecting with the CLI or with HeidiSQL? or both?

Comment: heidisql. cli is fine and now ive just left the password blank and now it works so its a non issue now sorry for the confusion