# How do I reset my root password in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble connecting to MySQL with from Ubuntu 16.04:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

which returns the error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I try starting the server with:

```
sudo service mysql start
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

the output is:

```
# 2017-01-26T20:11:45.329764Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-01-26T20:11:45.333031Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:11:45.336684Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:11:45.358956Z mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

If I kill the process with:

```
ps aux | grep "msyql"
kill -9 pid
```

and then run:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

I get:

```
2017-01-26T20:10:07.979813Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:10:07.984114Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:10:07.987546Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

It's an endless loop. So then what if I reinstalled from scratch?

First remove MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_install_db   // (deprecated command)
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

As far as here:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

or:

```
mysqladmin -u root password [newpass]
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Then it falls down.

I've tried following all of the answers here - [ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)

Sometimes a temporary password is stored according to others, but it's not stored in /var/log/mysqld.log as suggested

Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 4):

If you are running `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` and getting the following error:

```
2017-01-26T20:10:07.984114Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:10:07.987546Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists
```

It might be because MySQL 5.7 and above create the */var/run/mysqld* directory dynamically while running. When you stop it with `service mysql stop` to run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` , it's not available.

You can create it manually before running `mysqld_safe`:

```
service mysql stop
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Then you can change the root password or whatever you were trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

How you read this web page and tried the method(s) described there?

[Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Yes, I get as far as step 5 in the Unix like systems section, and I get this:

 mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
[1] 30542
# 2017-01-26T20:47:19.809930Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-01-26T20:47:19.813143Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:47:19.817689Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-01-26T20:47:19.820696Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. Link-only answers are discouraged as they become useless should the link go dead. Consider keeping the link for detailed explanation but adding a coarse list of instructions here.

Comment: @CollinD i agree with you. the reason is i'm not sure if a link in comments is clickable and i just wanted to make it easier to go to the page. and that page is an official document and may be useful for others with similar problems.

Comment: Links in comments are [totally clickable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: @snakespan i had the similar problem a while ago and had it resolved based on the instruction in that page. but i can't remember exactly what i did except i saved the link. Seems you got a brand new installation and it puzzled me why you should have such problem.

Comment: @Shiping I agree. I might have to start from scratch and clear everything down. Very rarely do you get these issues with fresh installations.

Comment: @snakespan here is another post with similar problem, probably you already read it, but just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

Comment: Yes I've also read that one. There were a few solutions that came close, but ultimately failed due to the: " Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) " issue or " Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists." error messages when running mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & or mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &

Comment: @snakespan sorry it may be too late, but you could force mysqld to listen to  a port instead of socket, so you can connect via the port. not sure though if it'd solve your problem.