# MySql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I've tried multiple solutions from StackOverflow but haven't had any success.  I'm on Mac OSX (Sierra 10.12.3) trying to create a new database and user.  From terminal I enter:

```
mysql -u root
```

which outputs this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

To try and resolve it I stopped mysql from 'System Preferences', then from terminal typed:

```
sudo mysqld_safe —skip-grant-tables
```

I opened a second tab and entered:

```
mysql -u root
```

Then from in mysql:

```
update mysql.user set password_expired = 'N', authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword') where user = 'root';

flush privileges;
```

I then restart the computer (killing the process with CMD + C doesn't work).  After restarting, trying `mysql -u root` still produces the same error.

I am able to access mysql via a MySQL client and a non-root user.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have added a password so use `-p` and add the password.

Comment: @Stony I tried that and it doesn't work.  After entering my password I get the same error.

Comment: _Exactly_ the same error?

Comment: Exactly the same except the end is `using password: YES`

Comment: so, not exactly the same then. NO means you are not sending a password to MySQL. YES means you are sending a password to MySQL but the incorrect one. Did you specifically set a password for the mysql root user when you installed MySQL? By default there is no password so you can use mysql -u root -p and hit enter.

Comment: I know it is not Mac, but on my Windows I for some reason have two versions of sql server. localhost and MySQL 5.7. Could that be part of the reason?

Comment: @Niagaradad a random password was originally generated when I installed mySQL.  I've also updated the password in the past.  I've tried my latest password, the original password, and blank.  All have the same error.

Comment: @SomeStudent just checked each directory in my `$PATH` and only one of them has a file named `mysql` so I don't think that's the problem (`/usr/local/mysql/bin`).

Comment: Here's another question, how did u get ur SQL? Did it you get it from their website, or as part of a larger package like say MAMP?

Comment: @SomeStudent downloaded it from their website.

Comment: what's the output of ` select Host,User from mysql.user where User='root';? do you have a localhost there?

Comment: @Ivan there is one row returned.  Host = localhost, User = root

Comment: Blank password and no password are different.  The former is the empty string; the latter is not asking for a pwd.

Comment: @RickJames I've tried `mysql -u` with `-p` and without it - both cases show an error.

Comment: I had that only when I had not connected mysql server in XAMPP before.

Comment: Just to confirm: You are sure you are running MySQL 5.7, and not MySQL 5.6 or earlier version. And the plugin column contains "mysql_native_password".  (Before MySQL 5.7, the password hash was  stored in a column named *password*. Starting in MySQL 5.7, the password column is removed, and the password has is stored in the *authentication_string* column.) And you've also verified the contents of authentication string matches the return from PASSWORD('mysecret'). Also, is there a reason we are using DML against the mysql.user table instead of using the `SET PASSWORD FOR` syntax?

Comment: @spencer7593 that was it!  The plugin column for my root user was blank.  I updated it to be `mysql_native_password` and now life is good.  Stick that in an answer and I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Look this post [root localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y). hop help you

Comment: Another question here, I have this working when i am using mysql client on commandline, but on the code with hte correct password its not working and i am getting this error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Just to confirm: You are sure you are running MySQL 5.7, and not MySQL 5.6 or earlier version. And the plugin column contains "mysql_native_password". (Before MySQL 5.7, the password hash was stored in a column named password. Starting in MySQL 5.7, the password column is removed, and the password has is stored in the authentication_string column.) And you've also verified the contents of authentication string matches the return from PASSWORD('mysecret'). Also, is there a reason we are using DML against the mysql.user table instead of using the SET PASSWORD FOR syntax?
>    – spencer7593

So Basically Just make sure that the Plugin Column contains "mysql_native_password".

Not my work but I read comments and noticed that this was stated as the answer but was not posted as a possible answer yet.

Answer (score 49):

For security reason mysql -u root wont work untill you pass -p in command so try with below way

```
 mysql -u root -p[Enter]
 //enter your localhost password
```

Comment: Thanks but i've tried with and without -p argument and no difference.  @spencer7583 solved the problem.

Answer (score 17):

```
mysql -u root -p;
```

And mysql will ask for the password

Comment: hi, i am trying to delete and reinstall xamp to allow remote access (bec I have faced a lot of access problems to mysql). I have deleted xamp, but not able to delete mysql. the only command worked for mysql in my case is yours

Comment: could you help pls?

Answer (score 6):

just use:

```
$ sudo mysql
```

without the "-u root" parameter.

Comment: Using this command I then get prompted for my password.  I enter it and get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to skip the password prompt for some reason, you can input the password in the command (Dangerous)

```
mysql -u root --password=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

You must run your mysql by xampp-controle.exe in folder XAMPP. After that login:

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: I'm not using XAMPP or Windows.

Comment: OK, you must controle does mysql run.

Comment: Not sure what that means.

Comment: Does mysql running?

Comment: Yes MySQL is running.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the root password is not what you think it is? Have you checked the file /root/.mysql_secret for the password? That is the default location for the automated root password that is generated from starting from version 5.7.

```
cat /root/.mysql_secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (on Windows, i don't know how in others), if you have changed password a now don't work.

1) kill mysql
2) back up /mysql/data folder
3) go to folder /mysql/backup
4) copy files from /mysql/backup/mysql folder to /mysql/data/mysql (rewrite)
5) run mysql

In my XAMPP on Win7 it works.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by **@Niagaradad** helped me. I was entering the wrong password the whole time.

Notice the error message

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ayaz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It says, Password: Yes. That means I am sending the password to SQL and that is wrong.

Usually **root account doesn't have password** if you haven't set one. If you have **installed mysql via homebrew** then **root account won't have a password.**

Here is the comment.

> so, not exactly the same then. NO means you are not sending a password to MySQL. YES means you are sending a password to MySQL but the incorrect one. Did you specifically set a password for the mysql root user when you installed MySQL? By default there is no password so you can use mysql -u root -p and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to `Edit Inbound Rules` on my AWS RDS instance to accept `All Traffic`. The default `TCP/IP` constraint prevented me from creating a database from my local machine otherwise.