# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO), can't reset password either

Tags: mysql

**I can't get access to my MySQL databases.
Problem:**

> *root@server:~#* mysql -uroot

*ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*

**Trying to reset password:**

> - /etc/init.d/mysql stop
> - mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

**leads to:**

*root@server:~# ... mysqld_safe Logging to syslog. ... mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'. ... mysqld_safe Directory
 '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.*

**as a result:**

> root@server:~# mysql -uroot

*ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket    '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)*

> root@server:~# mysql -u root -p

*Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742075/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passw) and many others.

Comment: No, not at all. Where in this link do you see the solution? I've already read 20 Threads on Stack Overflow about it and did 5 Tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

> sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Now I'm in ! :-)

> DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
>
> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'the_password';
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Thanks to Maoz Zadok in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778695/12226925

Answer (score 0):

Directions from Section B.4.3.2.2 for [Resetting Root Password on Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

1. As root, kill the mysqld process.
2. Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a single line: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';`
3. Start MySQL: `mysqld --init-file=/path/to/file-from-step-2 --user=mysql`
4. Delete the file you created in step 2

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly this doesn't worked for me.