# Rails database issue - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, mysql2

I have looked through a lot of similar solutions but have been unable to resolve my issue so hopefully someone can help.

I have joined a Rails project and need to pull data via a dump.sh file to enable me to work locally. Whenever I run the required command, I receive this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If I try `mysql -u root` I see the exact same error message.

Trying `mysql -u root -p` requires my password to be entered (it is the same password in the `database.yml` file) which is kind of weird - surely this step should not work based on my error message?

My `database.yml` file looks like this for development:

`development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_development
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: "password_is_here"
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

I feel like I am missing something really basic here, but cannot for the life of me work out what it is :-/

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the database exists and has been migrated so `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` are not the issues.

EDIT2: My test database has the same information

Comment: Try this answer on stack overflow [ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y) to configure mysql correctly on linux

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see anything there that I haven't already tried (including setting new passwords, restarting the SQL server etc). I still continue to receive the "using password: NO" message.

Comment: How about your **dump.sh** script looks like ?. It will be helpful to answer the question if you posted the codes of dump.sh with your  question.Have you added mysql privileges to it?.

Comment: It's something I cannot (contractually) post I am afraid - it definitely works though as others in my team have run it without issues.

Comment: Ok you have two solutions . You can change the permissions of ***dump.sh*** using **chmod** or **chown** commands to work locally on your computer. Or you can add the these changes to ***database.yml*** file as , add `default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_development`

Comment: Have you tried flushing privileges and granting privileges to `rails_user` on both your test and production database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this error before, that was because the database.yml contain some special characters that can't see in normal mode of text editor. I suggest to try to create totally new database.yml file from scratch then input database info again manually, restart the server to check the result.

Comment: Must have been something connected to that as you mentioned. Re-wrote it from scratch and it works perfectly now so thank you!