# How to resolve login issue in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have been working with mysql for accessing some database but now when I try to login I get the error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Try look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y Are you dealing with web applications? In that case, make sure that your database config file is properly structured and has the correct info in it.

Comment: Do you give GRANT access to the user? https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/

Comment: @Martin - I have gone through it. It doesn't work. I don't want to reinstall mysql. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Roy - How can I grant the permisiions when I am not even able to login?

Comment: Do it from you cPanel

Comment: @Roy - How can I access cPanel?

Comment: search same thing on google please.