# Can't Monitor MySQL using Prometheus, Docker and prom/mysqld-exporter image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor MySQL using Prometheus, Docker and prom/mysqld-exporter. I have already searched many sites and follow all of them step by step, but unfortunately I didn't get the result that I wanted.

There are two main problem:

1. I can't even connect to mysql with user and password I defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

The error is:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have also checked the popular questions in stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y) one and tried all of them, but it still doesn't work properly. I have also add `command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` to configuration of mysql in docker-compose file.

2. Whenever I set the `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` environment variable,I've faced with http timeout of the metrics on `localhost:9104/metrics`, whereas I can get `localhost:9104` without any problem and while I add some flags but it doesn't works!

Here is my files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE= db
      - MYSQL_USER= mostafa
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD= ghadimi
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
      - 33060:33060

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports: 
      -  8080:8080

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: 
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

  mysql-exporter:
    image: prom/mysqld-exporter
    container_name: mysql-exporter
    ports:
      - 9104:9104
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-exporter/.my.cnf:/root/.my.cnf
    environment: 
      - DATA_SOURCE_NAME='mostafa:ghadimi@(localhost:9104)/db'
      - collect.info_schema.tablestats=true
      - collect.info_schema.userstats=true
      - collect.info_schema.query_response_time=true
      - collect.auto_increment.columns=true
      - collect.binlog_size=true
      - collect.perf_schema.eventsstatements=true
      - collect.perf_schema.eventswaits=true
      - collect.perf_schema.file_events=true
      - collect.perf_schema.indexiowaits=true
      - collect.perf_schema.tableiowaits=true
      - collect.perf_schema.tablelocks=true
    depends_on: 
      - mysql

volumes:
  mysql:
```

.my.cnf:

```
[client]
user=mostafa
password=ghadimi
```

and prometheus.yml:

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 15s
    external_labels:
        monitor: 'my-monitor'
scrape_configs:
    # - job_name: 'prometheus'
    #   static_configs:
    #       - targets: ['localhost:9090']

    - job_name: 'mysql-exporter'
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['mysql-exporter:9104']
```

**PS:** I didn't face with any error, whenever I executed `docker-compose up` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "localhost" in enviroment of mysql exporter in docker-compose to

mostafa:ghadimi@(mysql:3306)/db