# mysql error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, windows

I just installed MySQL on my pc using tutorial on the YouTube every thing set to default options during the installation the tutorial said that after the installation done I should open the `MySQL 8.0 commend line client` and then I should type the password to connect the database but when I open it and after I type my password it's close when I press enter so I tried to use the work MySQL workbench it's gives me this popup error [image: error]   I search on the internet for solution I got this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y/42967789#42967789) but this solution for ubuntu none of the answers are not applicable on windows but some other solution gives me some other errors :

```
C:\Users\husam>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ***************
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Users\husam>mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I want to use the MySQL with ruby on rails project on windows 10

Comment: as you installed it, you gave root as superuser a password, this you must use **exactly** as typed in. you can always reset the pasword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: so I need to reset the password !!

Comment: When you don't wrote it down pr remember it, i don't see another chance

Comment: I just follow the instructions here  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html I create txt file ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'; and cd to  "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"   and run   mysqld --init-file=D:\\mysql-init.txt  I get an error

Comment: 2020-04-23T08:33:57.062306Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 9748
2020-04-23T08:33:57.067150Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test

Comment: ower-test
2020-04-23T08:33:42.067932Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-04-23T08:33:42.068193Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: 2020-04-23T08:33:42.102726Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-04-23T08:33:42.103083Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: it may be silly but the issue was in my new password that's contains this ' one quote symbol and after I removed it every thing works fine 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue wan in my password it's contain `'` so I removed it and everything works fine