# How to restore Data from a MySQL dump file, from host to Docker container via. Windows

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, restore, dump

I've read through a lot of alternative solutions but I haven't found anything specific to my problem. I'm using Windows PowerShell, and I need to restore/populate my DB Docker container that I created using the following code below.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=DB -e MYSQL_USER=PASSWORD -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD -d mysql:8
```

Then to populate my DB (Restoring data from an sql dump file) I enter in the following code below to point my .sql file to the DB container I created.

p.s. I have to place in dbl quotes due to windows syntax. I also can't place in the following character '<' before entering in my path because it's improper syntax for Docker on Windows)

```
docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c "exec mysql -uroot -p "$root"" "C:/filePathHere/all-databases.sql"
```

After I hit enter I receive the fallowing error below

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Even after creating a new DB connection and adding in a new user/password, which I use root for both User/Pwd. I still get denied access.

Anyone know what I may be doing wrong ? It's important I populate my DB container this way and avoid manually restoring the dump file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please read the contents of what I'm asking. All the syntax that's provided in what you considered a duplicate question is for a Linux OS. I need assistance with Windows. That link is something I've already read into and it did not provide me a solution to my problem.

Comment: Apart from the file paths its all Docker code. That is not OS dependant

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for re-opening my question. I understand what you mean as Docker code isn't OS dependent, however the syntax for the paths of pointing a .sql file to a docker container, has only ever shown syntax of an operator '<' placeFile here which I can't do for windows and I havent found a solution for this. Do you perhaps know a solution ? Or a better way to ask my question to get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my question, and first to start off, the cmmd using the fallowing syntax with an '<' operator is not supported in PowerShell v1 and as of v5, it's still not... You can either use regular cmmd line or place your docker cmmd syntax inside a .bat file and run it through windows powershell.

You cab refer to this site that provides the fallowing solution for the file path syntax using windows ***(I provided the code from the link below)***. [Windows: Back up & restore MySQL data from Docker container](https://kim-jangwook.medium.com/windows-back-up-restore-mysql-data-from-docker-container-e118adc79492)

And if anyone is getting a similar error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

A solution that worked for me was to add the fallowing cmmd ***mysql -u root*** to your Restore cmmd. Found this solution via this link here [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)

**BACK-UP**

```
C:\docker\directory> docker ps

C:\docker\directory> docker exec container-id /usr/bin/mysqldump -u username database-name > dump.sql
```

**RESTORE**

```
C:\docker\directory> docker ps

C:\docker\directory> docker exec -i container-id /usr/bin/mysql -u username database-name < dump.sql
```

**If you want to use docker-compose command**

```
    # To BACK BACKUP
C:\docker\directory> docker-compose exec -T container-name /usr/bin/mysqldump -u username database-name > dump.sql

    # To ROLLBACK 
C:\docker\directory> docker-compose exec -T container-name /usr/bin/mysql -u username database-name < dump.sql
```