# Can't connect to mysql, get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I enter mysql -u root -p and put in my password and get this error, I have uninstalled and reinstalled mysql and changing the password for root but still get this message.

I have looked and looked for solutions but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to enter mysql through my terminal, instead I get get the error above and can't get into mysql even after uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that you are using the wrong credentials to connect, try to consult consult the general log file `/var/log/mysqld.log` to copy the initialization password.

if that doesn't work you can try this approach:

1. check if MySQL is installed and running on your system `sudo service mysql status`
2. Reset the root password:

- stop the server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
- start the server in safe mode: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
- try to connect: `mysql -u root`
- reset the root password: `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword'), password_expired='N' WHERE User='root';`
- flush privileges: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- quit the server: `quit`
- stop the safe mode server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

3. now you can start the MySQL server again: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`
4. Use the correct credentials to connect (with the new password)

check out previous answers to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y/42967789#42967789) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw).