# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Want to configure a password as root being the user

Tags: mysql

I have just downloaded WAMP. I want to configure a password for the MySQL root user using MySQL console. No password has been set previously.

The following is the input

```
    mysql-> use mysql
    Database changed
    mysql-> UPDATE user
         -> SET Password=PASSWORD<'elephant7'>
         -> WHERE user='root';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near  'WHERE user='root'' at line 3

Comment: https://hsnyc.co/how-to-set-the-mysql-root-password-in-localhost-using-wamp/

Comment: So Windows and old MySQL? You didn't mention what version of MySQL **nor** the Operating System you are using. Hence all the answers are :"Try this.." You should always post your details. Downvoting.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('elephant7');
```

or, in latest versions:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root = 'elephant7'
```

You can also use:

```
UPDATE user SET password=password('elephant7') WHERE user='root';
```

but in Mysql 5.7 the field password is no more there, and you have to use:

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('elephant7') WHERE user='root';
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much, the last one worked for me. When i wrote the same lines as you it didn't work but on copying and pasting yours it did. I am sure there was no difference in syntax or case in both cases.

Comment: Happy to know it! Be kind and vote/accept answer. Regards

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET` is the ticket for me. I'm using MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: you need to `flush privileges` after all that or any change won't take effect.

Comment: `SET PASSWORD FOR root = 'elephant7'` results in latest versions of MARIADB (10.1.44) in error:
`ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number`. And `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('elephant7');` does nothing, giving `0 rows affected`.

Comment: Both of the bottom two resulted in syntax errors for me. The top two can't be executed because I'm using the --skip-grant-tables option. Version 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4

Answer (score 121):

I was using MySQL 8 and non of the above worked for me.

This is what I had to do:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Comment: This worked for me on: `mysql ver 8.0.16 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`. Update query resulted in syntax error.

Comment: Yup... only this works on: mysql ver 8.0.16 for mac installed with homebrew

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me been googling forever!!

Comment: This query is worked for me but new password is not working. It's only start to work after I recreated root user https://askubuntu.com/a/784347/160368.

Comment: maybe you need to `flush privileges` after this query for new password to work. can you try and update? and upvote if the answer was helpful :)

Comment: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: That wroks for me in version 8.0.25. Mac m1 pro.

Answer (score 70):

On MySQL 8.0.15 (maybe earlier than this too) the `PASSWORD()` function does not work anymore, so you have to do:

Make sure you have stopped MySQL first (Go to: 'System Preferences' >> 'MySQL' and stop MySQL).

Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass:

```sql
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Then

```sql
mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
```

Finally, start MySQL again.

Enlightened by @OlatunjiYso in this [GitHub issue](https://gist.github.com/zubaer-ahammed/c81c9a0e37adc1cb9a6cdc61c4190f52).

Comment: mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

Comment: @NativeCoder this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153059/mysqld-safe-directory-var-run-mysqld-for-unix-socket-file-dont-exists

Comment: The solution for me was to run mysqld_safe as root user. Then execute the version 8 style query

Comment: The steps above worked for me. I tried many different ways but only the above approach worked for me: Mac OS 11, 8.0.26 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: In my case, a Ubuntu running in a Windows 10 64bits, was necessary for a Mysql 8 run before the ``` flush privilages ``` the folow comand ``` update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root'
``` . This workaround I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded

Comment: Thank you; this worked for me on MySQL 8.0.28 Homebrew on MacOS 10.

Comment: This worked for me, MySQL 8.0.33 on Ubuntu 22.04.2. After all the steps, for restart I used `sudo killall mysqld` then `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`. If I attempted restart with just `sudo service mysql start` it would hang.

Answer (score 8):

I have problems with set password too. And find answer at 
[official site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html)

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'your_password';
```

Comment: The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 7):

This is the only command that worked for me. (I got it from M 8.0 documentation)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'*' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YOURPASSWORD';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YOURPASSWORD';
```

Comment: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 4):

The following commands (modified after those [found here](https://devanswers.co/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/)) worked for me on my WSL install of Ubuntu after hours of trial and error:

```sql
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root mysql
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
flush privileges;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password_here';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It may be helpful:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('pwd') WHERE User='root';
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ERROR 1064 (42000) or ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected in Mysql 5.7, you must specify the location of the user table, the location is mysql.table_name Then the code will work.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=password('elephant7') WHERE user='root';
```

Comment: It is necessary to `flush privileges` which is being missed by many answerers. Thank you Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password("elephant7") where user="root"
```

Comment: Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Answer (score 2):

From the mysql documentation version: 8.0.18:

A superuser account `'root'@'localhost'` is created. A password for the superuser is set and stored
in the error log file. To reveal it, use the following command:
`shell> sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`
Change the root password as soon as possible by logging in with the generated, temporary password
and set a custom password for the superuser account:

```
shell> mysql -uroot -p
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass4!';
```

Comment: This is just for centos. Not working on ubuntu flavours.

Comment: I don't think so, it's a SQL command, actually I ran it on Windows seven

Comment: I've tried. At least not working for MySql Server 8.x Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: regardless of whether it works for you or not, SQL is SQL. It's OS agnostic. @hiclas is right.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password-here';
```

Try it once, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

While using mysql version 8.0 + , use the following syntax to update root password after starting mysql daemon with --skip-grant-tables option

```
UPDATE user SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password')
```

Comment: I am running version 8.0.21 using --skip-grant-tables. This throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me.

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password-here';

Answer (score 0):

For mysql 8.0.23 based on [Official Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html)

ALTER USER root@localhost SET ='New_Password';

For Windows 10 environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. click on start manager.
2. select MySQL and open it.
3. write the below code and press enter button

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('elephant7');

Answer (score 0):

For mysql 8.0.28

1. [thor@john ~]$ sudo -i
2. [root@app01 ~]# mysql -u root -p
3. mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssw0rd123';
4. mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: This information was already available in other answers. I don't see why it needs to be repeated over and over again.