# Unable to change password in SQL

Tags: sql, passwords

I am a newbie to SQL, I am following a course where I was asked to change the password.

I inserted this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD(‘password’) WHERE User='root';
```

and received this error msg:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '('pwd') WHERE User='root'' at line 1

I tried option presented in this post: 
[ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Want to configure a password as root being the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099028/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-want-to-configure-a-pa)

All of them return the same Error. Can you help? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to remove: PASSWORD after the authentication_string attribute. The field has been deprecated.

So, this should work:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=‘password’ WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: With this command the password will not be hashed, it will be saved as is! if you run the command `SELECT user, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;` you will that the `root` user  will have `password` as password.