# Error 1064 (42000) Failed to grant privileges

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I follow the instructions grant database privileges to rails.
I used the following code:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON demo_proejcts_development.* TO'rails_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'
```

The demo_proejcts_developments is a database I created and I want to grant the privileges to the rails_user account

But it gives me an error,

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'' at line 1

I have tried to use ` to cover the project name, `demo_projects_development`, but it stills failed.

And more, I tried to separate the comment as two line via 'alter user', it still failed.

Comment: did you check this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099028/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-want-to-configure-a-pa?rq=1

Comment: I have tried it, but they are not too similar

Answer (score 4):

You can not use the IDENTIFIED BY in GRANT statement.
check mysql documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

If you don't have the rails_user already set then you can create with

```
CREATE USER 'rails_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and with following statement you can give permission for all priviledges with

```
GRANT ALL ON demo_proejcts_development.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost';
```