# Mysql Export Database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a hosting which included some database problem is I can not access to mysql.

database are in .ibd / .frm

I have a few problems:

- I don't know the password of mysql ( I did not create it) and don't know how to reset it
- I don't know how to export the database. I tried to install phpmyadmin but because I don't know the password I can not connect
- I tried to connect with Mysql Workbench but I got the result: Failed to connect to mysql (lost connection to Mysql Server at "reading initial communication packet, system 0

When I try to follow procedure to reset mysql password I did first:

```
sudo mysql stop
```

but I get the following error:

```
sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers.d/README: No such file or directory
stop: Unknown instance:
```

How can I get access to this database and what is the best way to export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several issues here.
First of all you need to check your sudo setup and privileges:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/482932/sudo-unable-to-stat-etc-sudoers-d-readme-no-such-file-or-directory

Second, you don't stop the service like this.
Assuming that you have openrc it would be:
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

And finally you have to start mysql in safe mode to change the root password.
Follow this thread:
[MySQL root password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change)

Comment: Thank you, when I check sudo setup and privileges by ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/, I get: total 4
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 Feb 11  2014 README. I did how you mention the mysql stop and start. I found maybe the problem. When I start again I got this error: * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full! That is why maybe I can not restart mysql. Do you have any idea what I can do with this partition?

Comment: Thanks for the help, after my previous message, I did clean the disk reset password and now I can use phpmyadmin. However I don't know how to see the database from /etc/mysql/mydata It is not on my phpmyadmin

Comment: After you changed the password you have to start the service normally, not in safe mode.
check the status with:
/etc/init.d/mysql status
In phpmyadmin you have to configure the servername (localhost) and Port (3306) in case you install it on the same server as the mysql-service.
Before you setup phpmyadmin you can check that your server is running correctly by running the mysql client this way:
mysql -u root -p
it will ask you for your root password, when everything is correct it drops you to the mysql shell

Comment: you are a king @juliokarl thank you! everything works until now. Just need now to figure out how to merge all of these databases