# Mysql reset password

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I am trying reset my root password for mysql service, and I get the following error:

```
mysql> update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("password") WHERE USER='root';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '("password") WHERE USER='root'' at line 1

I was trying to change `"` to `'` or `` ` `` and the same error appears.

Comment: Can you use the `SET PASSWORD` query like described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL root password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change)