# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Can't create connection with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu

I created a Spring Boot project and I want to connect with a database.

This is a .property file

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/tracking
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
server.port=8084
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

In MySQL username=root which doesn't have a password.

mysql port=3306

I get the following error when running the project.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
SQLError.java:129
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
SQLError.java:97
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
```

How do I solve this error?

I'm working with the Ubuntu operating system.

Also, I use `mysql -u root` command in the terminal to connect mysql it gives same error.
hence I used `sudo mysql -u root` I can sucessfully use mysql shell

Comment: change your password and put that in config, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change

Comment: set up a user account with a password, off course there is a password for root user, https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-windows-linux

Comment: as others have written - set up a password. But besides this, just now  your not trying to login without a password but with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is the privileges' problem. Try below command at the MySQL server side.

```
->GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tracking.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
->FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Reference :

- [https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/#:~:text=To%20GRANT%20ALL%20privileges%20to,TO%20%27username%27%40%27localhost%27%3B](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/#:%7E:text=To%20GRANT%20ALL%20privileges%20to,TO%20%27username%27%40%27localhost%27%3B)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.i did it early. i can solve this problem   temporary for only 'tracking' database

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
spring.datasource.password=''
```

to

```
spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: already i changed it and tried again. but it gives same error

Comment: How did you grant the user to access the tracking db?

Comment: I never thought this would work for me haha...