# the website is down after change the root password

Tags: mysql, drupal, root

I'm using drupal 8 & MySQL 5.7.28
After I change the root password in MySQL database. then change the credentials in sites/default/settings.php. The website shows the following error
 `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`
Also I check apache logs but there is no error related to the database.
UPDATE
I found the following error in the mysql server logs.

```
[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'DBIP' (using password: YES)
```

the following command I run to update the root password

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

any advice.

Comment: maybe a typo in one of them look in `/sites/default/settings.php` and eventually change the password again

Comment: @nbk I try to change the password with no luck, also I write the old password, and the site goes back again [without resetting the root password to the old one].

Comment: you have  to flush also the privileges see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484420/5193536
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: @nbk I did with no luck

Comment: after changing the password, can you access the database, in  such cases u have usually the wrong database,

Comment: @nbk please check the update above

Comment: there are another way see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html