# connecting mysql through command prompt

Tags: mysql

I have query regarding connecting mysql to comand prompt.
I did:

```
open cmd prompt
telnet localhost com 3306
 I RECEIVED REPLY as---
```

some instructions mentioning

```
telnet [-a][-e escape char][-f log file][-1 user][-t term][host [port]]
-a     attempt automatic logon. same as -1 option except uses the currently logged on  user's name.

-e   Escape char to enter telnet client prompt.
```

and some more...

but is it right?? or i am lost???
kindly help.

Comment: any reason why you can't use the "mysql" command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to MySQL from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

do not telnet to your mysql database.

Instead use the mysql command, a UI like [db visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) (they have a pay version and a free version), or the free ui that comes with maria db (a drop in replacement for mysql).

more more info on the mysql command, try running `mysql --help` or find it in the [mysql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/)

**Edit:** more info added here.
Telnet is not a "command prompt", it is a communication protocol (check out [telnet protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) on wikipedia) and a program (that uses the communication protocol to communicate).  You can not connect to mySql with telnet because mySql does not use the telnet protocol for communication.

I have only accessed mySql for jdbc, so I'm not sure how to solve your problem.  I know there is a c api interface for mySql as well.  Sections "20 Connectors and APIs," and "15 Replication" in the [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable suggestion.but y can't i connect mysql using command prompt when i can do d same for other ports.. and my final aim is to connect a microcontroller to the mysql that will keep on dumping data on mysql. any suggestions?