# Unable to connect login mysql databse using terminal

Tags: mysql, unix

I am writing below command to login MySQL

```
$mysql -u root -p root
```

But I'm unable to login and terminal show me message

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'root'
```

Anyone know, How to login MySQL using terminal?

Comment: please remove password "root" mysql -u root -p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connecting to MySQL from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, remove "root" after -p tag, because here root is database name not password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

So you have Two option to login MySQL,

1. Try `mysql -u root -p` It will login for whole Databse
2. Try `mysql -u root -p [database name]` it will login for particular database

For further learning you can refer [this dcumentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/)

Comment: Thanks for explanation in shorts, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The command you tried actually tries to use a database called `root` inside that mysql server. Such database apparently does not exist, which is why you get the error.

Instead simply try: `mysql -u root -p`

You will be asked for the password in an interactive manner.

If no password has been set yet (fresh install), then just try: `mysql -u root`

To learn about such things you really have to start reading documentations. A good starting point is the "man pages" typically installed on unixoid systems which offer a wealth of information on each available command. Just try a `man mysql`! It specifically shows the commands syntax right at the beginning: `mysql [options] db_name`. So the command accepts options (the `-u <username>` and the `-p`) and then an optional database name.

Comment: Thanks for the help.