# How to login to mysql 5.7 database?

Tags: mysql

I am on windows 7 and downloaded mysql 5.7 to be ran on localhost.

I started server with command:

```
mysqld
```

Next I opened another command line and typed

```
mysql
```

This returns error :

```
error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password NO)
```

Next i typed

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Empty password and got the same exception.

Here is option file `my.ini`:

```
[client]

port=3306



[mysqld]

port=3306

#здесь прописываем свой путь к директории установки

basedir="D:\Programs\mysql-5.7.17-winx64"

datadir="D:\Programs\mysql-5.7.17-winx64\data"

character-set-server=utf8

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode=""

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

skip-external-locking

key_buffer_size = 16M

max_allowed_packet = 1M

table_open_cache = 64

sort_buffer_size = 512K

net_buffer_length = 8K

read_buffer_size = 256K

read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
```

Did password change for default user `root` in mysql 5.7?

How to solve this exception?

Comment: The Password was set by the Installation of mysql.

Comment: How to read it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connecting to MySQL from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line)

Comment: You can not read it

Comment: I tried answer in that link but it is what I did already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

You can refer this link ..usually the default password will be the same for root.

Comment: Thank you. init-file helped me.