# MySQLi is enabled but not loaded in Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, windows-server-2008

I've installed PHP5.6, PHP7.0, PHP7.2 in my server with `extension=php_mysqli.dll` enabled.

The project is written for PHP7.0, able to connect db with PHP5.6, but not in 7.0/7.2

May I know how can i do further testing to find out the problems? No sign of MySQLi in phpinfo().

Comment: The phpinfo should tell you which php.ini is being used, so check the extension is enabled in the correct .ini

Comment: Yea, all correct! I'm using either 7.0 or 7.2, i check my php.ini carefully

Comment: I'm sure it's enabled in php.ini. How can i diagnose further?

Comment: Can you connect to the databases with the `mysql` command line tools, this will prove that the connectivity is there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line).

Comment: @NigelRen No problem! The same stack of code able to connect DB server via PHP5.6 (hosted in another server)