# How to retrieve Airflow data from it's database

Tags: mysql, airflow

Hi I am working on a project to display more visualization in my dashboard from the Airflow data. I am struggling on how can I query Airflow database directly to retrieve such data. Is there a way how can I retrieve data from Airflow database? Thanks

Comment: Based on the tag I assume you're using mysql, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line) answer your question?

Comment: I know how to connect to a database but I don't know where can I get the Apache Airflow credentials.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but don't you have to pass the credentials to airflow to allow airflow to connect to the database? From [Set up a Database Backend](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html) I think that the credentials should be in `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` for which you must have needed to create a user and password beforehand

Comment: Thanks for the Set up a Database Backend. I was using SQLlite3 and that why I did not have any database connection.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not set up any MySQL connection airflow was using SQLlite3 and that is why I was struggling to connect to the database. This was fixed by create a Airflow database in MySQL.