# Laravel app deployed to Heroku failing to make DB queries to PlanetScale MySQL database

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku

Despite successfully deploying my Laravel app to Heroku, the app is failing to make database queries to my PlanetScale-hosted MySQL database. The following error comes up:

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '<username>' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `table_name`) ``

`<username>` is the username provided by PlanetScale. The credentials worked perfectly when the Laravel app was hosted locally. I also changed the TLS/SSL root configuration to match the one suggested by PlanetScale for Ubuntu (which Heroku apps run on), and  gave the above error instead of the one I was receiving before which suggested the TLS error.

Here is my `database.php` file:

```
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'aws.connect.psdb.cloud'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'table_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'certificate' => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'),

            ...

            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'),
            ]) : [],
```

Edit: I am using the credentials I created in PlanetScale with the Admin role.

Comment: The error suggests that the connection is being denied due to incorrect credentials.

Comment: @esQmo_ I am aware. But I am using the credentials provided to me by PlanetScale.

Comment: This could be that the environment variables in your Heroku app are not set correctly?

Comment: maybe planetscale is rejecting the your app hosted from server?

Comment: Did you check your .env if you also provided the correct information?

Comment: run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I did. Doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Did you check the .env? Is the information correct?

Comment: you said you can connect to your planetscale from localhost, can you connect to your database using a terminal? `mysql -u USERNAME -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME -p` if yes, check in your production too

Comment: for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131945

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yes, it works from the terminal.

Comment: In localhost? how about in heroku?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth what do you mean? Accessing the remote MySQL works from terminal in my local machine. Is there a way to access the my Heroku server's terminal?

Comment: Yes you can access via terminal in your local machine but you said you cannot access the mysql from your app hosted in heroku. that is why I asked if you can also access the mysql via terminal from heroku. also you did you answer my earlier question. Is the information in the .env in your heroku correct?

Comment: I solved it thanks. I had to set the Heroku environment vars; there is, however, no .env in Heroku. I had to do this manually with the Heroku CLI.