# MySQL Workbench UBUNTU 22.04.3 LTS - Cannot Connect to Database Server "User interaction failed"

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, interaction, failed-to-connect

After clicking on MySQL Connection I'm getting the message:
Cannot Connect to Database Server "User interaction failed"

I tried to reset root password via ALTER USER but same message "User interaction failed". See image below:
[MySQL WorkBench message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLARX.png)
I also tried to open Manage Server Connections and put the password on Parameters session, but got the same message "Could not store password: user interaction failed" (see image):
[MySQL WorkBench message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmWkd.png)
Did anyone pass by a situation like mine and could solve it? Does anyone have a clue about solving this issue?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you verify the connection settings by connecting dirctly to the console for the MySQL server, without Workbench just to make sure the connection settings are correct?  But you can't reset a password on a server you can't connect to so that is the reason you have the same error results.

Comment: Thanks for your insight!
Following your help, I did it via systemctl command and the status is active (running). It was also running when I tried what I've described above.

Comment: Ok sounds like you confirmed the server is up, but that doesn't mean the connection information is correct.  Now keep in mind the following link includes php information as well, but you can try to connect to your MySQL server from the command line using the credentials you believe to be correct.  If you can get it to connect in the command line, it should also work in Workbench.  LINK -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Comment: I appreciate your help! After your last advice I went to my notebook to try doing what you've told me. For my surprise when I tried to click on the local connection, it worked. I left the connection unprotected by password. So I went to the command line and made the secure Installation. I came back to the workbench and this time it correctly asked the password so I could connect properly. It sounds like I had an spurious bug in my Lenovo computer. Thank you once more for this help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it going, good luck with your project!