I cant Create a Connection between Python with MySQL
So recently i try to use MySQL and Python ( MySQL 8.00, Python 3.12 ) i view some code in W3 School to create a connection between ( i use Visual Studio Code as my text editor ) and i try this code
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

print(mydb)

its just for testing but it wont work, any advice or other way to do it?
So i want to make a Connection between MySQL and Python so i can Code it in one text file
here is the error message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 334, in _open_connection
self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'yourusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Username\Documents\Programing Development Study\Advance Learning on Python\List System 1.1.py", line 3, in 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 322, in connect
return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 151, in init
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1399, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 339, in _open_connection
raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'yourusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Access is denied so are you sure your user has access and the password is correct? I would verify this by connecting "outside" of code - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/how-to-connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Access denied means that your code can connect to mysql, but you provided incorrect user name and / or password or the user does not have access to tthe requested resource.
